# Rusty in perl. How do I read in a datafile, and then replace an entire line within that file if a specific string is found

Tags: perl

I need some quick perl help.  Here is what I want to so:

1) run my perl script from the command line, and pass in as an argument a data file
2) Search the passed in data file, and look for the first occurrence of a word in a string. Replace the entire line that string resides in, with another line of text.
3) Save the updated file to itself (replace within the file).

So for example, something like this:

```
./myPerlScript.pl data.txt
```

with the data file being something like this:

```
_DATA__
path/to/some/file
path/to/some/other/file
path/to/SUBTSTRING/file #replace entire line if SUBSTRING is found
path/to/file
```

but the actual `data.txt` is updated (NOT written to a new file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as in any other language.

```
use Fcntl qw( SEEK_SET );

my $qfn = $ARGV[0];
open(my $fh, '+<', $qfn)
   or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");

# Read contents of file into $file.    
my $file; { local $/; $file = <$fh>; }

if ($file =~ s/^.*SUBSTR.*/foo/mg) {
   seek($fh, 0, SEEK_SET)
      or die("seek: $!\n");
   truncate($fh, 0)
      or die("truncate: $!\n");
   print($fh $file)
      or die("print: $!\n");
   close($fh)
      or die("close: $!\n");
}
```

---

Another way:

1. Create a temporary file in the same dir as the original file.
2. Read from the file  and write the modified contents to the new file.
3. If an error occurs, delete the temporary.
4. Delete the original.
5. Rename the temporary.

It's what happens when you do the following when using a sufficiently recent version of Perl:

```
perl -nle'print /SUBSTR/ ? "foo" : $_' -i file
```

We can access this functionality through `$^I`

```
$^I = '';
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   say /SUBSTR/ ? "foo" : $_;
}
```

This approach has two advantages:

- There's no data loss on error.
- It allows us to read the file line by line (thus saving memory).

And three disadvantages:

- Requires enough disk space for both the original and the modified file.
- Requires permission to create a new file.
- File loses whatever owership and permissions it originally had.